# Software and files to external drive

Tags: 12.04, home-directory, external-hdd

My OS (Ubuntu 12.04) is installed on my 40gb internal hdd. I have a 320gb external that stays attached at all times. I would like to have software installed & runnable on the external hdd instead of the internal. I would just install Ubuntu on the internal, but the mother board is unable to boot from anything bigger than a 250gb drive (I have tried). 
If possible, I would also like my Home folder to be located on the external too (meaning I want saved/downloaded files to go to the external hdd by default rather than having to manually navigate to it). When I click the Home folder icon on my desktop, I want it to open the external hdd directories.
Are these things possible? If so, please give step-by-step instructions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to move /home to its own partition

When you want to move your /home directory to another partition (because your HDD is full), here is a Step-By-Step guide how to do it.

***Note: You want to print this page or write it down because you need the commands during the moving of your /home directory! You can't access your browser during this process.***

#### 0. If it isn't already, format your HDD as ext4.

#### 1. Determine the size of your home directory by opening a Terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) and entering:

```
du -sh /home
```

The result should be something like

```
34G /home
```

#### 2. Enter a text console by hitting (CTRL + ALT + F1) and get temporary root permissions:

```
sudo -s
cd /
```

#### 3. Mount the destination partition (the external HDD)

Enter `fdisk -l` into the Terminal to get a list of all partitions. Remember the name of the external HDD. Then execute

```
mkdir /mnt/tmp
mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/tmp
```

and replace `/dev/sdXY` with the name of your external HDD (e.g. /dev/sda5).
This mounts your external HDD.

#### 4. Copy the data from /home/ to the external HDD.

This can be done with:

```
rsync -avx --progress /home/ /mnt/tmp
```

#### 5. Test your /home partition:

Execute these commands

```
mount /dev/sdXY /home
```

where `/dev/sdXY` is your external HDD. Now you can test your new /home partition:

```
du -sh /home; mount|grep /home
```

The output should be something like

```
34G    /home
/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw)
```

#### 6. Delete your home partition

Now you need to delete the existing home partition. To do this, unmount the home partition and remove it:

```
umount /home
rm -rf /home/*
```

#### 7. Enter the new UUID into /etc/fstab

The last step is to enter the UUID of the external HDD into /etc/fstab. **This step is very important!**

Switch back to your desktop by hitting the keys CTRL + ALT + F7 (or F6, don't know which one is the right one).
Open a Terminal and enter `sudo blkid` in the Terminal and search for the entry of your external HDD. My entry would be:

```
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="bb288354-34a8-4716-9740-96aa9da99dac" TYPE="ext4"
```

Now open `/etc/fstab` with a text editor (i.e. gedit):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and add the following entry at the end of the file:

```
# /dev/sdXY 
UUID=YOUR-UUID-HERE  /home   ext4   defaults   0 2
```

But don't forget to replace YOUR-UUID-HERE with the UUID of the external HDD and /dev/sdXY with the name of your HDD (for example: /dev/sda5).

#### 8. Reboot so that the changes take effect.

Enter `sudo reboot` in a Terminal. After your PC has rebooted, your home partition should be on the external HDD.

If you have got any problems, feel free to ask in the comments.

I hope this post answered your questions.